# Function psi, vector potential, satisfying conditions

Tags: vector-spaces, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

Using spherical polar coordinates ($r, \theta, \phi$) verify that the vector $F = r^{-2}e_r$ is solenoidal. Find the function $\psi(r, \theta)$ such that $A = \frac{\psi(r, \theta)}{rsin \theta}e_\phi$ is the vector potential of $F$ satisfying $ \nabla \cdot A = 0$ and $F =  \nabla \wedge A.$

I've verified that F is solenoidal but can't find the function $\psi(r,\theta)$

Using

$x = rsin\theta cos\phi$

$y = rsin\theta sin\phi$

$z=rcos\theta$

$F = r^{-2}e_r = r^{-2}[\frac{1}{h_r}(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}i + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}j + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}k)]$

$F = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}})$

Then using $F \cdot \nabla = 0$

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}) \cdot (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta}})$

=...

$= \frac{-6}{r^3\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2 \phi}}$

At $(0,0,0)$ we get 0 which is required.

But then finding the function $\psi (r,\theta)$ I am unsure what to do.

When trying to find out $e_\phi$ in

$A = \frac{\psi(r, \theta)}{rsin \theta}e_\phi$

is it: $e_\phi$ = ($\frac{\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}i + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}j + \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}k)}{rsin\theta})$?

then doing $\nabla \cdot A = 0$

I get $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \frac{\psi (r,\theta)}{r^2sin^2\theta} = 0$

Then working out $F = \nabla \wedge A$

I get

$\frac{\psi (r,\theta)}{r^2sin^2\theta}[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} )- \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi})] = \frac{1}{r^2\sqrt{sin^2\theta + cos^2 \phi}}[\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}]$

and now I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Matt, try explicitly taking the curl and divergence of the proposed vector potential. This will then give you a differential equation for $\psi$.  I've tried reading your work and it doesn't look like you have done this.

Comment: Hint: Work in the Lorenz Gauge.  Using the Coulomb gauge is a bit more tedious